# Optimize for Tablets

Tags: android

I am creating an app which I want to have support for Tablets as well. I have followed the steps discussed on developer.android.com as well as many questions in SO. I am not able to get my head around as to why Play Store is still reporting that

```
Your Production APK needs to meet the following criteria:
Any required hardware features are normally available on tablets.
```

My Manifest file has the following declarations

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"  android:required="true" />
```

Since my app uses Telephony features, I have marked the required attribute as true here. If anyone has faced a similar problem and able to get it fixed kindly provide inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tablets don't "normally" have telephony features. They're tablets, not phones. Thus, if you require telephony hardware, then the app won't be presented to tablets which don't have telephony features. [This is documented](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/best-practices-for-honeycomb-and.html).

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But there are tablets like Samsung Galaxy Tab which have telephony support.

Comment: I think you got your head around it then. The broadband variants of the GTab will see your app offered in the play store. However, the vast majority of tablets doesn't have telephony features, so the app won't be offered to all tablets.

Comment: That is ok, I want to support only tablets that support telephony. So even with this optimization message from play store, will it be visible to tabs that have telephony?

Comment: Yes, it will show on any device that implements telephony -- note that some tablets may not accurately report the telephony feature (i.e. some 3G tablets which use cellular data as an alternative to wifi, but don't expose SMS or even RSSI). I'd suppose that on those tablets, your app wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: alright, i am trusting you and accepting this answer. I have a nexus 7 to test by which i am unable to check this for myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the code as follows:

```
    uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="true" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"  android:required="false" />
```

I have just changed the permission for using feature to requires="false".
By doing this, your app will be available for use and download on the tablet devices having calling feature and not on tablets not having the same.